# Why my parallel program on linear search using OpenMP is taking more execution time than the sequential linear search program?

Tags: time, parallel-processing, openmp, execution-time

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main()
{
    int i, key=85, tid;
    int a[100] =     {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33, 34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,6 4,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94 ,95};
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) private(i)
    {
        tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp for
        for(i=0; i<100; i++)
            if(a[i] == key)
            {
                printf("Key found. Position = %d by thread %d \n",     i+1, tid);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my parallel program.. I'm using `GCC` in `Fedora` and system is dual-core...
Actually i need to compare both sequential and parallel program for linear search and prove parallel is better than sequential.

Do i need to add user and sys time to calculate execution time for both sequential and parallel( as this uses two core)??

pls help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that the first thing you should do is set your program to tackle a much longer list to search.  For such a short list as you give in your example the time cost of setting up the parallelism is likely to far exceed any benefits.

Comment: I second High Performance Mark. The first thing that one has to learn in parallel processing is to evaluate how the parallel overhead compares to the amount of work done. This also implies that one has to learn what is the overhead of different parallel paradigms and implementations. In your case the overhead is many times higher which leads to very bad parallel performance. Also the `printf` call probably takes more time than iterating over the whole array in serial.

Answer (score 0):

It costs some time to setup the parallel environment. Try a much larger array. You should certanly see  a speed up.